# for in loop: prediction of different values from one variable within a logit model

Tags: r, for-loop, prediction, glm

I have estimated a demand function for football ticket sales (logit: 1 = ticket/block was sold, 0= ticket/block was not sold).

```
model_Gegner <- Ausverkauft_2 ~ Preis + Block + Gegner + Spieltagsklasse + Leistung_Heim + 
  Leistung_Auswärts + Temperatur + Unsicherheit + Wochentag+ Saison

Logit_Gegner <- glm(model_Gegner, data = train, family = "binomial")
```

As a next step, I would like to see what would be the highest possible price the club could charge to still sell the ticket.
To find this out I have designed a for in loop:

```
Preis <- c(1:100)
Preis

#test object: 
SpielRevenue <- subset(test, Datum == "2018-12-02" & Kategorie == "4" & Block == "15E")

#### for in loop 
for(p in Preis ){
  SpielRevenue$Preis <- p
  print(predict(Logit_Gegner,SpielRevenue, type="response")) 
}
```

Instead of the probabilities of selling a ticket at the different prices, I get the following:

```
      440 
0.6747067 
      440 
0.6688503 
      440 
0.6629412 
      440 
0.6569808 
      440 
0.6509704 
      440 
0.6449117 
      440 
0.6388061 
      440 
0.6326553 
      440 
0.6264611 
     440 
0.620225 
      440 
0.6139491 
     440 
0.607635 
      440 
0.6012848 
      440 
0.5949002 
      440 
0.5884835
```

Since I have only limited the prices to 100, I don't understand where the 440 comes from. There are 100x the 440 so you could assign the different prices to each 440. But this would be a big counting job.

I would like to have following result:

```
        1
0.6747067 
        2
0.6688503 
        3 
0.6629412 
        4
0.6569808 
        5
0.6509704 
        6
0.6449117 
        7 
0.6388061 
        8
0.6326553 
        9
0.6264611 
       10
0.620225 
     ...
```

I would also like to save the result in a dataframe if its possible.

The contribution goes in the direction of:
However, I haven't found any contribution that helps me with mine. If there is one, I am sorry for the duplication.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have found an answer to my question. If others have the same problem, I'll post it here instead of deleting my question:

```
Block15E <- matrix(nrow=100, ncol=1)

#### in for loop 
for(p in Preis ){
  SpielRevenue$Preis <- p
  Block15E[p,] <- (predict(Logit_Gegner,SpielRevenue, type="response"))
}

Block15E <- as.data.frame(Block15E)
colnames(Block15E) <- "Verkaufswahrscheinlichkeit"
Block15E$Preis <- seq.int(nrow(Block15E))
Block15E <- Block15E[,c(2,1)]
```

440 was the row number.
To escape the number, I created a matrix before the loop and took the index as the price in the second step.

Doesn't look really nice, but works :)